# Send input with angular router

Tags: angular

I need to send data to a component via the router.

I have the following (PUG):

```
a.subnav-link(routerLink="/transport/entity-list", routerLinkActive='active') Entity
```

and the router:

```
{ path: 'transport/entity-list', component: EntityListComponent, canDeactivate:[CanDeactivateGuard] }
```

`EntityListComponent` has an `@Input` (an object) and I don't know how to pass the data. I don't want to change the path...

Using Angular 2 RC6 and router 3 RC2

Comment: You can't pass data to `@Input()`s of components added by the router. You can use a shared service or a resolver (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard).

Comment: Can you write an answer with a very small example so I can validate it? thanks

Comment: Validate what? To me it's quite unclear what you try to accomplish. I only pointed out that routed component can't get values passed to `@Input()`s

Comment: What is unclear? Normal way to send data to a `Component` is through `@Input` so how do you do when you use a router? What is the best way to pass data?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html